# Polymorphic relationship One to One - Many to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have problems understanding the polymorphic relationship concept.

Let's say I have this [database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB8an.png) in a music store.

Each disc can have many categories, how ever there are 2 types of categories; Genre and Author.

Each category can have many discs. (Jazz can have many discs, David Bowie can have many discs)

Each category (author or genre) can have one attachment.

Is my schema correct?

Or what is the best way  to create it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the attachment.

As per your description

> Each category (author or genre) can have one attachment.

But your schema clearly shows a 1:N relationship between Discs and Attachements.

Everything else *looks* good, maybe if you're interested in implementation you should read: https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails